# Setting up development environment in eclipse for Android Samsung SDK

Tags: android, eclipse, samsung-mobile

Can someone please help me setting up development environment in eclipse for the android samsung sdk.
I'm using eclipse helios and try to add add-on site url  http://innovator.samsungmobile.com/android/repository/repository.xml

but it wont connect.
Has someone come across this issue?
Please help.
Thank you.

Comment: what kind of error you faced ?

Comment: did you install samsung drivers?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what kind of SDK of Samsung you are referring to, but the given URL is not valid, as you can see by simply opening it in a browser. You will be redirected to the developer site of Samsung.

That said, you should not need any Samsung SDK for pure Android development. If you install the Android development toolkit and the Android platform SDK, you are ready to go. You can create emulators "skinned" to look like certain Samsung devices out of the box (with Android SDK 21).

And if you are setting up a new environment anyway, please use Eclipse Juno instead of Helios. Otherwise you are missing one year of bugfixes and features in all the Eclipse tooling...

Comment: The URL is valid as an Add On Site for the Android SDK Manager

Comment: @Blundell I'm using Eclipse Helios. Can you please tell me how did you use this url as an Add On Site for the Android SDK Manager? Could you manage to get the SDK??

Comment: @Zeba it has nothing to do with eclipse, you just add it as a site in SDK add on manager.